# How to add data to a Java List?

Tags: java, list, addition

Please see the code below with which I am trying to create a List. Can anybody tell me why this code does not work?

```
class materialsStore {

    List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void add(String antikeimena){
        lista.add(antikeimena);
    }

    public List<String> getList(){
        return lista;
    }
}

public class finalState {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        materialsStore materialObj = new materialsStore();
        String stoixeia = input.nextLine();
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
            materialObj.add(stoixeia);
        }
        materialObj.saying();
    }
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: It looks like you take one line of input and add it to the list 10 times. Is that what the program is supposed to do? What does the `saying` method do?

Comment: `com.stackoverflow.HomeworkException`

Comment: i dont get any error but i just want to give the things through the main to get into the list!i want to insert things in the list from my keyboard!

Comment: How do you know the strings aren't being added to the list?

Comment: because when i run the program i cant insert things and it returns me an empty list

Answer (score 1):

You want to add to the list 10 times. So change your code to add `input.nextLine()` into the loop.

```
String stoixeia=null;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   stoixeia = input.nextLine();
   materialObj.add(stoixeia);
}
```

As a sidenote , classes in java by convention start with upper case so it should be `MaterialsStore`.

Answer (score 1):

If you pepper your code with System.out.println() statements to see what values are at various points, it may tell you what your problems are. Alternately, you can learn to set breakpoints in your IDE for debugging.